# Sublime Text 3 - How to detect if file is changed

Tags: sublimetext3

I've looked all around and can't find the answer.. 
Anybody who has used Atom will know what I'm talking about.
 In Atom, if you open a file, write some code, but then erase everything you've written before saving, it automatically detects that the file has not changed from its original state and therefore if you try to close the file, it won't prompt you asking if you want to save changes.. You can also see the edit icon disappear from the file tab. I love this feature.
 First of all, is it a package? What is it called? I can't even figure out how to search for it.. Most importantly, does Sublime offer this?

Answer (score 2):

> Most importantly, does Sublime offer this?

Yes, it does.

There's a top tab selector with a tab for each open file. On each tab, beside the file name, there's a cross sign (X) when the file has not changed since last 'Save'.

If file has been modified, the X changes to a solid small circle.

[image]

In case you 'undo' everything until your last 'save' situation, the solid circle becomes again an X. In case you close the tab, it doesn't ask for saving.

This is a native behaviour in Sublime; not a plugin.

Comment: yes, but you have to specifically use CTRL+Z in order for it to autodetect that the file has not changed.

Comment: Say you type "hello world" and erase it with backspace, it will still think the file is changed. However if you just CTRL + Z what you did, it will recognize correctly.